# Command 'scrapy' not found

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, scrapy

I am trying to get setup so I can write a python program to scrape a webpage but I cannot even do that yet because I need to get scrapy setup so I keep trying to type the following command in my shell: "scrapy startproject scrapy_javascript" but get the following error "command 'scrapy' not found"... And I do not know what is wrong.  I looked at similar questions but nothing that helped answer my question.  I am inside the scrapy folder I downloaded as well.

[image: Command line code]

Comment: `./scrapy ...` or `path_to_actual_command/scrapy`

Comment: did you install `scrapy` ? `pip install scrapy` ?

Comment: @furas Yes I installed scrapy but I cannot run it

Comment: I see you have folder `scrapy_splash` - did you install `scrapy` or `scrapy-splash` ? Did you get any error message when you install it ? You can also try in Python `import scrapy ; print(scrapy.__version__)` to see if it installed.

Comment: Your system is telling you that it is not installed. Make sure that you follow the [installation guide](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html) and that you do not get any error during any of the steps.

Comment: The same issue. Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Add Python bin folder (where executable of Scrapy is located) to your path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue. Fixed it so:
Drop your env
Create new
Install Scrapy